# Updating HTML Text From JQuery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple object created through JQuery:

```
var userSettings = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    username: "Jsmith"
};
```

The HTML is quite simple as well:

```
<p>First Name <span id="firstName"></span></p>
<p>Last Name <span id="lastName"></span></p>
<p>Username <span id="username"></span></p>
```

My question is, how do I write a simple function that will support adding more key/values to the object.  For this example, the function would simply update the text of the corresponding span with the proper ID.

**Additionally**

Parts of the object will not necessarily going to be handled through .text - is there a way to filter/define what method to use based off of something defined in the object?  For example adding in userColor: red would use .css rather than .text.

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/bce7ubqx/2/)

Edit: Updated Fiddle with Function

Comment: 1. This code does nothing. What is it supposed to do, and what have you tried? 2. This has nothing to do with jQuery (at least so far)

Comment: Oh, whoops - I forgot to include my function - http://jsfiddle.net/bce7ubqx/2/  - I'm not sure how to handle condensing it to run more effeciently with more parts of the object.

Comment: Please update the question as well. It helps to have all relevant information inside the question itself.

Comment: For that you need to chain jQuery. See [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bce7ubqx/4/)

Comment: Maybe I explained wrong - but my point is that certain key/values would use a different method.  So rather than using .text certain key/values would use .css

Comment: for that you need condition to check weather to apply text filter or css. Better option would be, you create a different object, and apply css loop same as this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be:

```
for (var key in userSettings) {
  if (userSettings.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    $('#' + key).text(userSettings[key]);
  }
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/bce7ubqx/1/

**EDIT:**

A possible solution (include your styles in object):

```
var userSettings = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    username: "Jsmith",
    styles: {
        color: "red",
        backgroundColor: "gray"
    }
};

for (var key in userSettings) {
    if (userSettings.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(key !== 'styles'){
            $('#' + key).text(userSettings[key]);
            if (userSettings.hasOwnProperty('styles')) {
                var styles = userSettings['styles'];
                for (var k in styles) {
                    if (styles.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                        $('#' + key).css(k, styles[k]);
                    }
                }            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/bce7ubqx/5/

Comment: If the object contained settings that wouldn't be updated via .text, is there a way to differentiate this in the loop?  For example, adding userColor: red in the object, but wanted this object to run with a .css method, how could I edit the loop to work based off of that?

Answer (score 1):

This will upadate the span text according to your `userSettings`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(userSettings,function(k,v){
        if($('#'+k).length)
            $('#'+k).text(v);
    })
});
```

**Edit:**

If you want to differentiate between `id` and `style`, add flags in loop

```
var userSettings = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    username: "Jsmith",
    styles: {
        color: "red"
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(userSettings,function(k,v){
        if($('#'+k).length)
        {
            $('#'+k).text(v);
        }
        else if(k=='styles')
        {
            $('any_selector_here').css(userSettings.styles);
        }
    })
});
```

See working [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bce7ubqx/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function update(){
    $("#firstName").text(userSettings.firstName);
    $("#lastName").text(userSettings.lastName);
    $("#username").text(userSettings.username);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough to achieve without jQuery at all:

```js
var userSettings = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    username: "Jsmith"
};

function setElementText(id, text) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    Object.keys(userSettings).forEach(function(key) {
        setElementText(key, userSettings[key]);
    });
});
```

```html
<p><strong>First Name</strong> <span id="firstName"></span></p>
<p><strong>Last Name</strong> <span id="lastName"></span></p>
<p><strong>Username</strong> <span id="username"></span></p>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bce7ubqx/3/)

Of course, if you're trying to learn jQuery, the other answers are valid.

Comment: Thank you.  Not sure if you saw my recent edit, about handling more than the .text (or in with JS setElementText).  This is a reason I'd prefer to use jQuery.  Using something like .css would help greatly.

Comment: This can be as elaborate as you need it to be... your userSettings object can hold internal objects, not just strings. Use this data to direct values to the proper HTML section (content, class, style...)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your script

```
var count = 0;
   $.each(userSettings, function(i, value) {
   //alert(count);
      $("p span:eq("+count+")").attr("id", value)
      count++;    
});
```

You can also add css attributes in this technique.

http://jsfiddle.net/bce7ubqx/7/